# Connect to SQL Server with knexjs, Unable to acquire a connection

Tags: sql-server, connection, database-connection, connection-string, knex.js

After trying looking at dozens of examples, and reading most of the docs, and trying many different variations, and changing many settings within SQL Server,  I've finally broke down to ask for help with this one.

I successfully connected to a tblTextKnex with mssqljs using the exact same connection string which SQL Server accepts, but have not been able to with knexjs for some time now.

I get the following warning and error:

> Knex:warning - calling knex without a tableName is deprecated. Use knex.queryBuilder() instead.

and

> Unhandled rejection Error: Unable to acquire a connection

This is the unsuccessful/offending code that I believed should work.

```
  var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mssql',
    connectionString: "Initial Catalog=TextKnex;Data Source=localhost\\TESTINSTANCE;User ID=my_user_id;Password=my_password;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
  });

  knex().connection().then(() => {
     knex('TextKnex').table('Products')
        .select('Products.Price as Price')
        .then((product) => {
            console.log('log product', product);
            console.dir('dir product', product);
            logger.info('Query Data: %j', product);
     })
  });
  knex.destroy();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, there is no `connectionString` attribute and `connection()` query builder method is documented to not work (and is not checking if pool has been connected). Also synchronously called `knex.destroy()` in the end destroys your knex instance, before any queries or connections would have been made.

Try this:

```
  var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mssql',
    connection: {
      connectionString: "Initial Catalog=TextKnex;Data Source=localhost\\TESTINSTANCE;User ID=my_user_id;Password=my_password;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    }
  });

  knex('TextKnex').table('Products')
    .select('Products.Price as Price')
    .then((product) => {
      console.log('log product', product);
      console.dir('dir product', product);
      logger.info('Query Data: %j', product);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      knex.destroy();
    });
```

or

```
  var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mssql',
    connection: "Initial Catalog=TextKnex;Data Source=localhost\\TESTINSTANCE;User ID=my_user_id;Password=my_password;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
  });

  ...
```

In knex tests mssql connection is done a bit different way: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/test/knexfile.js#L132

Comment: Neither the first nor second options you offer work, which is surprising considering knex.org states "The connection options are passed directly to the appropriate database client to create the connection, and may be either an object, or a connection string:"

Comment: Also I tried changing the version from 4 to 3.3.0 as this has also caused issues for other people in the past. This also has not worked,

Comment: Also using the suggested format in the test files did not work.   knex = require('knex')({
    dialect: 'mssql',
    connection: {
      user: "computername\\kyles2",
      password: "p_w",
      server: "127.0.0.1",
      database: "TextKnex",
      port: 59438
    }

Comment: I haven't used mssql myself yet, but I've been working on setting up mssql tests to knex CI. I might be able to help after I have that ready and have tested out how mssql works exactly (for now there has been other contributors responsible for mssql).